# Easiest way to plot phase/amplitude/impulse response for zeros/poles in z-plane

Tags: matlab, poles-zeros

I want to experiment to understand how poles/zeros affect the impulse/amplitude/phase response.
So I wonder if there is any software where you can mark poles/zeros and get this? (I have not found any yet)
Or otherwise how can this easily be done in matlab?
For example [image: for a second order if you have poles in 0]
How can I get the responses then? o is zero and x is a pole.

Comment: `[z,p] = butter(4,0.15);     zplane(z,p)  `. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Depending on how you define your system, `pzmap(sys);` can also be used.